# Get the Data from a Json String in codename one

Tags: java, json, netbeans, codenameone

am getting a json from the server and i managed to save it into storage,

```
{"FirstName":"Festus","MiddleName":"Kilaka","LastName":"Mutinda","MemberNo":"1886","IdNumber":"3125638","PayRollNumber":"87","PhoneNumber":"254743901110","EmailAddress":"FESTUS@GMAIL.COM"}
```

all i need is to read through it and get each variable and attach them to my strings.
i tried the code below but am getting an error.

```
private String str_response;       
private String memberNoLabel = "";
private String nameLabel = "";
private String idNoLbl = "";
private String staffNoLbl = "";
private String emailAddLbl = "";
private String PhoneNumber = ""; //Storage.getInstance().readObject("PhoneNumber").toString();
private String AccBalanceLable = "50,500";
```

str_response = (String) Storage.getInstance().readObject("profile.json");
Log.p("Reading profile.json from storage.", 1);

```
    byte[] bytes_mydetails = str_response.getBytes();
    JSONParser json_mysaccos = new JSONParser();
    try (Reader is_mysaccos = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes_mydetails), "UTF-8")) 
    {
        Map<String, Object> map_saccos = json_mysaccos.parseJSON(is_mysaccos);
        java.util.List<Map<String, Object>> objMydetails = (java.util.List<Map<String, Object>>) map_saccos.get("MemberDetails");
        System.out.println("No of Details: ---------> " + objMydetails.size());

        for (Map<String, Object> objDetails : objMydetails) 
        {
            String name1 = (String) objDetails.get("FirstName");
            String name2 = (String)objDetails.get("MiddleName");
            String name3 = (String)objDetails.get("LastName");
            nameLabel = name1+name2+name3;

            memberNoLabel = (String)objDetails.get("MemberNo");
            idNoLbl = (String)objDetails.get("IdNumber");
            staffNoLbl = (String)objDetails.get("PayRollNumber");
            PhoneNumber = (String)objDetails.get("PhoneNumber");
            emailAddLbl = (String)objDetails.get("EmailAddress");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error @ saccos: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

am getting this error

```
Error @ saccos: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and it says its from the line

```
System.out.println("No of Details: ---------> " + objMydetails.size());
```

have tried all available documents and tutorials i could get, but i cant figure out this, help...

Comment: You have `map_saccos.get("MemberDetails")` - but where is `"MemberDetails"`? It is not in the JSON provided in your question. (I added `java` and `json` tags to your question, so it reaches a wider audience).

Comment: This is JSON of a single entry. Not of a list so as @andrewJames said the `map_saccos.get("MemberDetails");` won't work. I think you got it from the server but already saved the entries. Also did you look in the developer guide at property based parsing which is more seamless?

Comment: Thanks i have looked at it, am sorted.